# Nodejs как сохранить файл в кодировке windows-1251

Tags: node.js, файлы, кодировка, файловая-система, cp1251

Использую модуль fs и там нельзя сохранить файл в cp1251.
Пробовал так:

```
fs.writeFileSync(process.cwd() + "\\olink.cpp", {encoding: '1251'});
fs.writeFileSync(process.cwd() + "\\olink.cpp", {encoding: 'cp1251'});
fs.writeFileSync(process.cwd() + "\\olink.cpp", {encoding: 'windows-1251'});
```

Comment: у writeFileSync другая сигнатура функции https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options. а для изменения кодировки данных есть iconv и другие пакеты

Comment: iconv же конвертирует текст в другую кодировку, а я хочу сохранить в файл.

Comment: сохраните в файл результат конвертирования

Comment: А сохранять в какой аргумент здесь указывать encoding:

Comment: никакой________

Comment: ••••••! у меня это получается, а должно быть Привет!

Comment: данные в какой кодировке? просматриваете в какой кодировке?

Comment: данные в в кодировке utf8

Comment: конвертируется при помощи iconv всё верно в cp1251 но сохранить не получиться в cp1251, сохранять можно только в ascii | utf8 | latin1

Comment: вот [этот скрипт](https://pastebin.com/W2ST22Z6) даст вам файл в кодировке utf8 и файл в кодировке cp1251. если файл в кодировке cp1251 показывается у вас чем-то не понятным - просто настройте кодировку в ide или где вы там его смотрите

Comment: здесь нужен именно iconv а не icon-lite

Comment: я когда пытаюсь установить iconv:
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\SpecialKeyNodeJS\node_modules\iconv
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
....

Comment: абсолютно всё равно. ставьте  icon-lite

Comment: const converter = iconv('utf8', 'cp1251');
Здесь возникает ошибка
iconv is not a function

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv-lite#usage

Comment: Большое спасибо что попытались помочь, но всё не помогло :(
я решил проблему так:
`require('child_process').exec(process.cwd() + "\\gppcore.py", function (err, stdout, stderr){});`
и вот что в скрипте на питоне:

`import os

f = open("obj/olink.cpp", "r", encoding='utf8')
str = f.read()
with open("obj/olink.cpp", 'w', encoding='cp1251') as f2:
    f2.write(str)
    f2.close()
os.system("gpp.bat")`